# Card flip program in HTML not fliping properly

Tags: html, css, web, transition, transformation

[Link to the Card Flip program!](http://codepen.io/Falcon43/pen/wBdgem)

The card do get flipped but then when it turns over there is an error for a split second which disappears immediately.How am i supposed to remove that error?
 I guess the error is mostly occuring when the backface-visibility:hidden; is used.

```css
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;
}
body{
  background:#000;
}
.wrapper{
  margin:11% 32%;
  position:relative;
  border:5px solid black;
  width:390px;
  height:360px;
  perspective:800px;/*If u add some perspective to the container*/
}
.card{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  transition:-webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.175,0.885,0.320,1.275);/*Cubic ease giving a spring to it*/
  transform-style:preserve-3d;/*2Settings...one show child elements as 3d and other as flat...so just make it always on*/
}
.card:hover{
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg); /*When hovered it card flips*/
} 
h2,h3{
  font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-weight:300;
  color:white;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
p{
  color:white;
}
.front{
  border:15px solid white;
  text-align:center;
  width:360px;
  height:330px;
  position:absolute;
  backface-visibility:hidden; /*I dont wanna see your back*/
}
.back{
  border:15px solid red;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:400;
  width:360px;
  height:330px;
  position:absolute;/*We dont want block ar something, we want right inside div where it was supposed to be without considering other elements*/
  backface-visibility:hidden;/*I dont wanna see your back*/
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);/**/
}
h2,.back{ 
  background: #F00943;
}
h3{
  text-align:left;
}
h2{ 
  background:rgba(240, 9, 67, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  top:-80px;
  padding:10px;
  width:350px;
  left:-5px;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper"> <!--Front & back are inside Card,Card is inside the Wrapper-->
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="http://www.dailybackgrounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/cute-cat-hd-image.jpg" height="330px" width="360px"/>
          <h2>Miss Mittens</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="back"><br/><br/><br/>
          <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Loves:</h3><br/>
          <p>Strings, cuddles, and <br/>long naps in the sun.</p><br/>
          <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dislikes:</h3><br/>
          <p>Bath, things that aren't sparkly and <br/>anything reassembling work.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateX(0deg);` to `.front`.

[Demo Here](http://codepen.io/Ruddy/pen/gbRdxK)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  background: #000;
}
/*SeaseOutBack:cubic-bezier(0.175,0.885,0.320,1.275);*/

.wrapper {
  margin: 11% 32%;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 390px;
  height: 360px;
  perspective: 800px;
  /*If u add some perspective to the container*/
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: -webkit-transform .7s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
  /*Cubic ease giving a spring to it*/
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  /*2Settings...one show child elements as 3d and other as flat...so just make it always on*/
}
.card:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p {
  color: white;
}
.front {
  border: 15px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 360px;
  height: 330px;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) rotateX(0deg);
}
.back {
  border: 15px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 360px;
  height: 330px;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
h2,
.back {
  background: #F00943;
}
h3 {
  text-align: left;
}
h2 {
  background: rgba(240, 9, 67, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  top: -80px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!--Front & back are inside Card,Card is inside the Wrapper-->
  <div class="card">

    <div class="front">
      <img src="http://www.dailybackgrounds.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/cute-cat-hd-image.jpg" height="330px" width="360px" />
      <h2>Miss Mittens</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Loves:</h3>
      <br/>
      <p>Strings, cuddles, and
        <br/>long naps in the sun.</p>
      <br/>
      <h3>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dislikes:</h3>
      <br/>
      <p>Bath, things that aren't sparkly and
        <br/>anything reassembling work.</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Note: *Tested and working in Chrome, in the codepen version I turned on auto autoprefixer so you will have to put this in your code manually.*

Comment: @AishwaryaR Your welcome, if you could accept the answer that would be great. It will allow people that view your question to see it has been answered and may also help someone in the future.